# Home server, where to start

Tags: server, vpn, proxy, openvpn, nas

I'd like te set up my desktop at home as a server with multiple services:

First: NAS and remote desktop control, in browser, but terminal only (like telnet) is fine by me. 
Next: I would also like to have this connection through a VPN, so having a VPN server on it would be nice as well. Next i'd like to make it a proxy too, so i can, for example, connect with my laptop to the proxy over vpn and have a secure hotspot-connection (starbucks).'ll take care of security like firewall etc, unless it would be completely impossible to do these things securely, in that case i'd like to know it now ;).

I'd like to know: if it is possible to have these services (VPN, NAS, proxy, remote desktop, ...). If this is possible, which os to use (Debian? Ubuntu server? i have experience using ubuntu desktop but i'm open to try new things), which programs are best (openVPN? telnet? ...), i'll figure out how to install, set up and use them, but just hav eno idea about the landscape of servers and networking as a whole...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do NOT use telnet! Do you have any idea how insecure that is? Use SSH instead.

Comment: Are you sure you know enough about GNU/Linux to run a server? Judging by your question, it sounds like you don't know how to set any of the utilities up or even what software to use. My recommendation: if you want your server to be very secure and stable, and you're willing to spend a little bit of time setting things up, use Debian stable (currently Wheezy).

Comment: I *think* that the differences between `Ubuntu Desktop` and `Ubuntu Server` are minimal, possibly just the lack of a `GUI` in in `Ubuntu Server`. And you can easily remove it from `Ubuntu Desktop` or add it from `Ubuntu Server`, so it should be no big pain in any case. About `Debian`, I can't tell. But I strongly believe that all those service would be available both for `Ubuntu` and for `Debian`. Perhaps you should ask this question on `Super User` instead

Comment: Thanks! Scratched out telnet, ssh it'll be. Well, I have to start somewhere, don't I? i can go out there reading everything i can find on networking, but i thought it would be better if i had an idea where i was going and what tools i would be using before studying up on it. I think i'm going for Debian, never used it before, but i want to learn something else than ubuntu :) I've asked it on SuperUser, taking these comments in the edit, so this question can go, thank you all :)

Comment: Sorry, really I don't know what I was thinking but I wrote `Super User` instead of `Server Fault`

Comment: Great then. I remember when I first tried to run a server. I installed Ubuntu (should have used Debian, but I didn't know better then), and I ran a Google search for anything I had to figure out. What I think will be the hardest thing for you is getting Debian to work well with your hardware. If your hardware doesn't work 100%, add the non-free repos and install the non-free firmware packages. (I'm sure you'll be able to find more about that on the Debian Wiki). For NAS, you'll want Samba. As for proxy or VPN, I can't recommend anything because I don't know enough about them. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot @FuzzyToothpaste, i'm going with Debian, i'll figure it out. Samba is on the list!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Debian or a Debian based Linux distribution, then you should have a look into the free Debian Administraor's Handbook: http://debian-handbook.info/

You can also have a look at Debian Administratrion Site:
https://www.debian-administration.org/

About services, there are some examples in both sites.  But you should have a firewall in your server. I would recommend `ufw`(1) as a good firewall for a server for you to have a look at.

An alternative to VPN you could also use is IPv6, and let `gogoc`(8) mannage a IPv6 tunnel.  But you still need to have a firewall.

You might also want to look at OwnCloud as a file/cloud server.

Comment: I'm reading those sites as we speak :) I'll be using OpenVPN to start with, and i'll  try the ipv6-gogoc combo later on. A VPN would also take the role of a proxy. According to me, it sound legit. Any thoughts on this? I won't be using OwnCloud, it looks so fluffy :) Okay, ufw will have to do the trick to start with. Any ideas how this would work together with peerguardian?

Comment: `OpenVPN` seems like a ok choice.  The package/service `gogoc` is a service to connect your computer to IPv6 (specify host in `/etc/gogoc/gogoc.conf`) or your LAN network/s (router in `/e/g/gogoc.conf`) through a IPv6 over IPv4 tunnel.  In the last case you need  a firewall that manage FORWARD for IPv6. For `ufw` that needs to be set in another file, unless you have the latest version.  So I usually recommend `shorewall6` there.  All other servers, that doesn't work as a router, I prefere `ufw`.  I have never used `peerguardian`, so I don't know. OwnCloud replaces Gooles Drive and MS OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible, but some of it is complex.

Start with a base of Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS and install packages as you go.  Google and you will see that there is a huge amount of help for Debian and Ubuntu so you have a good chance of success.

I am doing this but I will use KVM and virtual machines for some functions, eg a minecraft server. NAS - If you have 2 physical machines you can have distributed raid 1 (DRDB) to protect your data, not a bad idea. I will be doing this and run the VMs on that.